# Unable to add 2 fields in my table

Tags: javascript, php, sql, symfony

I'm trying to insert data in my new table and this is the entity code

```
 <?php

    namespace IT\ITBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Famille
     * @ORM\Table(name="famille")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IT\ITBundle\Repository\FamilleRepository")

     */

    class Famille
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="lien", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $lien;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IT\ITBundle\Entity\Personne", inversedBy="familles")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)

         */

        private $personne;
        /**


         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille", mappedBy="personne",cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="enfant_id", referencedColumnName="id")

         */
        private $enfant;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set lien
         *
         * @param string $lien
         * @return Famille
         */
        public function setLien($lien)
        {
            $this->lien = $lien;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get lien
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLien()
        {
            return $this->lien;
        }

        /**
         * Set personne
         *
         * @param \IT\ITBundle\Entity\Personne $personne
         *
         * @return Famille
         */
        public function setPersonne(\IT\MITBundle\Entity\PersonnePhysique $personne = null)
        {
            $this->personne = $personne;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get personne
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
         */
        public function getPersonne()
        {
            return $this->personne;
        }
        /**
         * Set enfant
         *
         * @param PersonnePhysique $personne
         *
         * @return Famille
         */
        public function setEnfant($enfant)
        {
            $this->enfant = $enfant;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get enfant
         *
         * @return Personne
         */
        public function getEnfant()
        {
            return $this->enfant;
        }
        public function __construct()
        {

            $this->familles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

        }
    }
```

and this is my second entity

/**
     * @var Collection.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille",cascade={"persist","remove"}, mappedBy="personne")

```
 */
private $familles;
```

my controller is

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $controle = $this->get('Controles');
        if(($controle->is_Granted('Ajout personne Morale','Client/Societaire',$this->getUser()))==false){throw new AccessDeniedException();}
        $personne = new PersonneMorale();
        $form = $this->createForm(PersonneMoraleType::class, $personne);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $mails=$personne->getEmails();
        if(!empty($mails)){
            foreach($mails as $mail){
                $mail->setPersonne($personne);
            }
        }
        $adress=$personne->getAdresses();
        if(!empty($adress)){
            foreach($adress as $adre){
                $adre->setPersonne($personne);
            }
        }
        $tels=$personne->getTelecoms();
        if(!empty($tels)){
            foreach($tels as $tel){
                $tel->setPersonne($personne);
            }
        }
        $compteBancaires=$personne->getCompteBancaires();
        if(!empty($compteBancaires)){
            foreach($compteBancaires as $cmp){
                $cmp->setPersonne($personne);
            }
        }
        $contacts=$personne->getContacts();
        if(!empty($contacts)){
            foreach($contacts as $contact){
                $contact->setPersonne($personne);
            }
        }
        $familles=$personne->getfamilles();
        if(!empty($familles)){
            foreach($familles as $fam){
                $fam->setFamille($personne);
            }
        }
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $maxNum = $em->getRepository('ITBundle:Personne')->getMaxNumPersonne();
            if($maxNum == null){
                $personne->setNumpersonne(1000000);
            }
            else{
                $personne->setNumpersonne($maxNum+1);
            }
            $em->persist($personne);
            $em->flush();
           // return $this->redirectToRoute('Personne_morale_index', array());
            return $this->render('ClientsBundle:Morale:success.html.twig', array(
                'personne' => $personne
            ));
        }
        return $this->render('ClientsBundle:Morale:new.html.twig', array(
            'post' => $personne,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

as you can see I can save only"lien" but I wanna save personne_id and enfant_id
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpw1I.png)

Comment: got any error ? what is you question ?

Comment: as you can see i can save only"lien" but i wanna save personne_id and enfant_id enter image description here

Comment: any help please

Comment: Have you updated your database schema???

Comment: no i do all the code manually .shoud i update database shema and how i do this

Comment: and i can save only "lien" and other data no

Answer (score 0):

if the personne_id column do not exist in table structure,
run 

`bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`

for seeing the queries and 

`bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

to run them.

Also you need to persist Famille as the data for Personne_id is owned by Famille or add cascade persist to personne as well.

As Famille to Enfant relation is oneToMany, the famille_id will be stored in Enfant table once you persist Enfant.

Comment: if enfant is not a persisted object there is no point in saving enfant_id in relation to Famille, please correct me if thats wrong. Please update if by persisting Famille object, you were able to save Personne_id

Comment: Thinks asha for ur answer i wanna just explaine that enfant is not a table .i have enfant_id in famille table .personne has many famille and famille has many personne but i wont use ManyToMany .i need to save 'Lien' and enfant_id will be a personne .should i take the 'enfant_id' as autoincreament? Waiting for ur answer or proposition .thinks again

Comment: could you please add class personne  code as well in the question.

Comment: I did if u can see that

Answer (score 0):

class Personne

```
 /**
     * @var Collection.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille",cascade={"persist","remove"}, mappedBy="personne")

     */
    private $familles;
    /**
     * Add famille
     *
     * @param \IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille
     *
     * @return Personne
     */
    public function addFamille(\IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille)
    {
        $this->familles[] = $famille;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove famille
     *
     * @param \IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille
     */
    public function removeFamille(\IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille)
    {
        $this->familles->removeElement($famille);
    }

    /**
     * Get familles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFamilles()
    {
        return $this->familles;
    }
```